# Kill a subprocess with PyInstaller

Tags: subprocess, pyinstaller

I created a script that uses Python subprocess.Popen(...). When I click a button, I want to destroy this subprocess (I use subprocess.kill()). It works fine when I use Python.

However, when I "compile" my script with PyInstaller, this doesn't work. Indeed, in the Task Manager (Windows), there are two processes (one from a temporary directory [created by PyInstaller I guess]). And so when I click the button, a process stops, but not one created by PyInstaller.

How can I do to kill the 2 processes at once ?

Tkanks

PS : Sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to compile the 2 Python files? You have to use the path of the second compiled file when you use subprocess.Popen(...)